# How do I make a DAO in anchor?

Tags: anchor, spl, dao

I see theres a governance library in anchor spl, but i cant find any examples on how its supposed to work.

I already have a token in my program that i would like to use for vote weights,and i want to be able to have the dao vote on certain actions

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source governance program in the solana program library

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/governance

with a UI https://github.com/solana-labs/governance-ui, that can be accessed at https://realms.today/

The various READMEs explain how the system works.

Comment: You got an example for that though?